# obj missing material in three.js objloader

Tags: three.js, 3d, blender

I'm using the objloader in three.js but the .obj I'm working with does not load the material.  Everything is loading fine in three.js according to the console.  I have the three obj files in the same folder, they are - model.jpg, model.obj and model.mtl.

model.obj has both the reference to the mtl and the material to use like so:

```
mtllib model.mtl
usemtl $Material_0
```

model.mtl has the following:

```
newmtl $Material_0
Kd 0.6 0.6 0.6
Ka 0.05 0.05 0.05
Ks 0.6 0.6 0.6
illum 1
```

shouldn't there be a map line for the jpg in this as well or is there something else that's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't there be a map line for the jpg in this as well or is there something else that's missing?

Yes. Normally there should be an additional line like in the following example if the `MTL` actually refers to a texture (e.g. diffuse map).

```
newmtl $Material_0
Kd 0.6 0.6 0.6
Ka 0.05 0.05 0.05
Ks 0.6 0.6 0.6
illum 1
map_Kd diffuse.jpg
```

Comment: I thought so.  I added the line `map_Kd model.jpg` but it still doesn't display the material.  I converted the obj from a ply, which has the material displaying.  Obviously the conversion has ignored the material but what's odd is that it gave me an mtl with what I guess are the mapping coordinates for a material.

Comment: Can you verify if the geometry has texture coordinates?

Comment: I thought those were the coordinates in the mtl.  I'm not at all familiar with the obj format.  I've put the three files here if you need to see them - http://www.asquare.org/in-progress/obj/

Comment: UV-Coordinates are always part of the geometry (like normals or vertex colors). Unfortunately, your `OBJ` contains no texture coordinate. That's the reason why you don't see the texture. I suggest you import the OBJ in a tool like Blender and then generate uv-coordinates.

Comment: Will do, good to know what precisely the issue was.  Many thanks.